# For every value within a column that = 1, extract the the value from the 3rd row below it to a new dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dataframe

Say that I have data like so in R:

```
      Time    Max   Var
 1    1.1      1    5.3
 2    1.2      0    3.1
 3    1.3      0    2.5
 4    1.4      0    1.7
 5    1.5      1    7.4
 6    1.6      0    3.4
 7    1.7      0    3.3
 8    1.8      0    2.5
 9    1.9      0    1.5
10    2.0      0    1.2
11    2.1      1    9.4
 .     .       .     .
 .     .       .     .
 .     .       .     .
```

Each time `Max` = 1 (e.g., row 1), I'd like to extract the whole row that is 3 below it (i.e., row 4), and move these extracted rows to a new dataframe.  This would yield:

```
      Time    Max   Var
 4    1.4      0    1.7
 8    1.8      0    2.5
```

My attempts have been playing around with `seq` and the `dplyr` package with no luck.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the index of all the rows where `Max = 1` and add `+ 3` to it. Keep only those indices which are lower than the number of rows in the dataframe.

```
inds <- which(df$Max == 1) + 3
inds <- inds[inds <= nrow(df)]
df[inds, ]

#  Time Max Var
#4  1.4   0 1.7
#8  1.8   0 2.5
```

---

In `dplyr`, we can use `lag` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(lag(Max, 3) == 1)
```

and similarly with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[shift(Max, 3) == 1]
```